# Sort members case insensitively in sphinx-autodoc

Tags: python, sorting, python-sphinx, autodoc

From the [sphinx.ext.autodoc documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_member_order), the `autodoc_member_order` can be `alphabetical`, `groupwise`, or `bysource`.  Is it possible to sort alphabetically case-insensitively?  I would like to sort "Ratio" before "RGB".

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no built-in option for this in Sphinx unfortunately.

The results of object inspection are [sorted in this function](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/eacaaed1c7602da9a73aa31caf8addf824070ef2/sphinx/util/inspect.py#L223):

```
def safe_getmembers(object, predicate=None, attr_getter=safe_getattr):
    # type: (Any, Callable[[unicode], bool], Callable) -> List[Tuple[unicode, Any]]
    """A version of inspect.getmembers() that uses safe_getattr()."""
    results = []  # type: List[Tuple[unicode, Any]]
    for key in dir(object):
        try:
            value = attr_getter(object, key, None)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        if not predicate or predicate(value):
            results.append((key, value))
    results.sort()
    return results
```

You could try overriding the function by doing this:

```
from sphinx.util import inspect

def custom_safe_getmembers(object, predicate=None, attr_getter=safe_getattr):
    # type: (Any, Callable[[unicode], bool], Callable) -> List[Tuple[unicode, Any]]
    """A version of inspect.getmembers() that uses safe_getattr()."""
    results = []  # type: List[Tuple[unicode, Any]]
    for key in dir(object):
        try:
            value = attr_getter(object, key, None)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        if not predicate or predicate(value):
            results.append((key, value))
    results.sort(lambda (k, v): (k.lower(), v))
    return results

inspect.safe_getmembers = custom_safe_getmembers
```

I haven't had an opportunity to try this yet, so be cautious!